# Get friends of a user discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How do I get the friends of a user in discord.py? I am using slash commands so I can't use ctx. I have tried using `client.fetch_user(user).friends` but that results in an `AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'friends'`

Comment: There's no such thing like `.friends` in `discord.py`. There's also no way of accessing the friends list of a user – at least not in the way you want to.

Comment: What other way?

Comment: I don't know if Discord offers this as a scope, but you would need to authenticate to your bot with every single account.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know this API but if `client.fetch_user` is a coroutine then you need to use `await` -

```py
await client.fetch_user(user).friends
```

Edit: I looked it up - as @Domink said there isn't a `friends` attribute in the `discord.py` library

Comment: `friends` is not part of the library in any way. While your statement is correct, it's still the wrong answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**: This is impossible and there is no way to get around this.
**Long Answer**: `friends` was once an attribute of `ClientUser` class but this was during the time that discord still allows user bots (which means you pass a user token, not a bot token to your program). But as discord announces user bot is violating its policy, discord.py drops support of user bot, starting at `dpy2.0.0`. You can view that all of these user bot related methods were removed by the [migration page](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#migrating-2-0).